# Unable to run Android Virtual Device Manager “android avd” getting NullPointerException

Tags: android, adt, osx-elcapitan, android-sdk-tools

So i keep getting the following error after i opened up adroid avd from the cli by typing `android avd` and then click on the Device Definitions tab. It takes like 15-30 seconds until it errors out.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.internal_new_GC(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.GC.cocoa_new(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table.sendMeasureItem(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table.cellSize(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper_stret(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.expansionFrameWithFrame_inView(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table.expansionFrameWithFrame_inView(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSend_bool(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.NSRunLoop.runMode(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sleep(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.repository.ui.SdkUpdaterWindowImpl2.open(SdkUpdaterWindowImpl2.java:149)
    at com.android.sdkuilib.repository.SdkUpdaterWindow.open(SdkUpdaterWindow.java:111)
    at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.showSdkManagerWindow(Main.java:413)
    at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.doAction(Main.java:391)
    at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.run(Main.java:151)
    at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.main(Main.java:117)
```

OS X version: 1.11.3
Java version:

```
java version "1.8.0_73"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_73-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.73-b02, mixed mode)
```

Android SDK manager revision: 24.4.1

The system integrity protection enabled but like this `csrutil enable --without debug`. I head it can cause problems, so i guessed i mention it.

P.S: i followed [this tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-cordova-example--cms-25328) to set up the development environment.

I placed the downloaded sdk into `android-sdk` and put it in the `$PATH` variable like this:

```
# Required for android sdk
export ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/android-sdk
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/android-sdk/tools
export PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and was not able to fix it. The same stack trace is showing up for other problems as well, including [this one](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=434393) for Eclipse. It appears to be specific to El Capitan.

I was able to work around this by accessing the device manager from inside of Android Studio instead of from the command line. Not the most satisfying of solutions but, any port in a storm.